# onInputShowListener Android - Is it possible to detect if any soft keyboard is shown?

Tags: android, input, keyboard, listener, show

after fixing another problem in my Android Application, i came to another thing.

It would be important that i can do something, like hide some visual elements, if the SoftKeyboard so a Input like Swipe or the normal Android Keyboard is shown.

I've tried the onConfigurationChange="KeyboardShow" (pseudocode) but had no change to get a event when for example skype got shown.

So now my question is, is there any solution or function or listener, with which i can handle such a action?

I hope someone can help me.

Sincerly,
Mike Penz

Comment: You want to know if any keyboard is shown?  Or if a particular one is?

Comment: if any, softwareKeyboards not hardware.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There might be better approaches, but a possibility is to add: `android:configChanges="keyboardHidden"` to the manifest. That will fire with any keyboard changes, so the you will need to query the `Configuration` object

```
static Configuration prevConf = Configuration();
static int ignoreMasks = Configuration.HARDKEYBOARDHIDDEN_NO|Configuration.HARDKEYBOARDHIDDEN_YES;

onCreate() {
   prevConf = setToDefaults();
}
// all your code here

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged (Configuration newConfig) {
    int deltas = newConfig.diff (prevConf); // what changed?
    prevConf = newConfig;

    if (delta & ignoreMasks) 
        return; // you're not interested in hard keyboards.

    //  your code here 
}
```

I suck at bitwise operators, so you might need to work around that.

This is the API documentation:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#configChanges

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onConfigurationChanged%28android.content.res.Configuration%29

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Configuration.html

Comment: BTW, there is a related question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2150078/android-is-software-keyboard-shown with an answer using an indirect method relying on the change of size of your layout.