# Android: event when the soft key hides and shows?

Tags: android, android-webview

I want to perform some action when soft key pops up and also when it hides.

Is it any way to catch such function.

please advice.....

Comment: Hi param please have a look on my response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does not seem to be possible.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look on the following url

[onInputShowListener Android - Is it possible to detect if any soft keyboard is shown?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5995272/oninputshowlistener-android-is-it-possible-to-detect-if-any-soft-keyboard-is-sh)

Thanks
Deepak

Comment: Thanks Deepak, I tried onConfigurationChanged () but it not worked with 'keyboardHidden'.....